# Getting wrong entry price in pine script for long and short entries

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, algorithmic-trading, pine-script-v4

I am getting the wrong price entry in my pine script. I am using both long entry point and short entry point and wants to get the latest entry prices and based on these prices my stop loss is calculated. but I see that these entry prices are not correct. some time the long entry get the short entry price and vice versa. Please look at the code here

```
var float stopLossPriceLong = na
var float stopLossPriceShort = na
var float entryPriceLong = na
var float entryPriceShort = na
var float currentPositionLong = strategy.position_size
var float currentPositionShort = strategy.position_size
var float SL_Long = na
var float SL_Short = na

if (longSignal and currentPositionLong <= 0)
    // Buy when there is a buy signal and no long position  
    strategy.close("Short")
    currentPositionShort := 0
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    currentPositionLong := 1
    entryPriceLong := strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0)
    SL_Long := entryPriceLong * (1 - stopLossPercent/100)

//if (not na(entryPriceLong) and close <= (entryPriceLong * (1 - stopLossPercent/100)))
if(close <= SL_Long and currentPositionLong > 0)
    strategy.close("Long", comment = "SL Long") 
    currentPositionLong := 0

if (shortSignal and currentPositionShort <= 0)
    strategy.close("Long")
    currentPositionLong := 0
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
    currentPositionShort := 1
    entryPriceShort := strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0)
    SL_Short := entryPriceShort * (1 + stopLossPercent/100)

//if (not na(entryPriceShort) and close >= entryPriceShort * (1 + stopLossPercent/100))
if (close >= SL_Short and currentPositionShort > 0)
    strategy.close("Short", comment = "SL short") 
    currentPositionShort := 0
```

and here I am getting the text format on the chart

```
    + "\nEntry Price Long: " + str.format("{0}", entryPriceLong) +  "\nStop Loss Price Long: " + str.format("{0}", SL_Long)
 + "\nEntry Price Short: " + str.format("{0}", entryPriceShort) + "\nStop Loss Short Price: " + str.format("{0}", SL_Short))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are in this if block

```
if (longSignal and currentPositionLong <= 0)
```

You are not in a new position yet. You are just placing an order. But you are assigning the entry price to `entryPriceLong` in that block which will not work.

You should either do:

```
if (longSignal and currentPositionLong <= 0)
    entryPriceLong := close   // or open depending on your settings
```

Or have something like below in the global scope:

```
entry_price = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0)
```

Comment: entryPriceLong := close  this works but the prices are not exactly the entry and exact price. the other condition is showing only the last price and both are same for the shortentry and longentry